# Meaning of the lyrics 'I could do dead.'

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

In Korean rap music, I found these lyrics:

> I could do dead.

I can't understand the meaning. I feel it is grammatically wrong.
What is the right meaning of the sentence?
What is the meaning of 'do dead' in this sentence?
Is it right to say that?

Comment: Songs do not have to obey the rules of grammar, and rap songs are no exception.

Comment: Should you be listening to rubbish like this? Would your mother like to hear or read those lyrics?

Comment: I was going to edit and include "context" to the OP but sfter reading the digusting lyrics will refrain from doing so. Presumably the lyrics in Korean have the same meanings ...

Answer (score 1):

It is non-standard, and so grammatically wrong.

It is probably formed in analogy to "I could do lunch" (meaning that eating lunch is possible for me)   so the intended meaning is probably "being dead is possible for me."

But analysing lyrics,  especially lyrics of non-English artists, for grammar is a fools' game.

Comment: -- Also, what a disgusting song.  I googled the lyrics and no I feel dirty.

Comment: The lyrics are like something produced by a smutty-minded 13-year-old boy. Deeply deplorable and nasty.